# Main thread freeze the background thread operations in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, bluetooth, threadpool

For my iOS application, I am using the Charts library (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to plot lines on the graph continuously with the continuous movement of the graph. The modes of communication I am using are WiFi(using Modbus Library) and Bluetooth.
Data I am receiving in the recursive manner. The frequency of the response communication are:

WiFi: Average 12 responses in 1 second.
Bluetooth: Average 4 responses in 1 second.

Each response is responsible for drawing the lines on the chart.
The entries in each dataset will append with every response. Below is the code which we are using:

```
self.lineChartVw.data = chartLineData
```

it draws the line from start to end of each dataset's entry. The library is using CGContext to perform the draw operation.

While it is drawing, it somehow blocks the other operation i.e. my recursive request-response gets blocked and the app UI freeze.

I am performing the recursive request-response operation in the different thread using

```
modbusQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.iModbus.modbusQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
```

and performing the graph operations in the main thread which is responsible to update the data in the graph and render it on the UI.

How can I solve the issue of UI freeze? Why it is affecting the other thread which is running in the background?

I'm attaching the code here for better clarity.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HLXu5C4NBJKzjgSUxN_9DqAYzh4jHP-_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean with "recursive"? It is rather polling at a certain interval? Also, please post the relevant code here.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, Please check the attached file. Yes, recursive means we are pulling the data from the device at a certain interval (100 ms)